# PyQt5 How to temporarily close the main window after opening a dialog box?

Tags: pyqt5

I want that when I click a button in the main window, it will go to the second window. I used the hide function and hid the main window, but when I finished the process on the second window, I want to return, but when I exit the second window, the program is already ending, because the first main window was already ending when I was in the second

Comment: What do you mean by "removed the title"? Are you referring to the title *bar*? And by "hide" do you mean *minimize*?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should show your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A suggestion: in the 2nd window's `closeEvent`, show the main window back.